# Cluster points by distance

Tags: qgis, vector

The full story is, I have a bunch of GPS points with up/down accelerometer readings from vehicles and I'm trying to map where there may be rough road conditions. However, there ends up being a ton of points which I would like to group to show a general area which is generating these points. The Cluster symbology is nice, but I would like a table to show the results and do other analysis.

I would like to group a set of points within a range of each other, like how the "Point Cluster" symbology works in QGIS, but with the output as a table. I would like the output to be something like {grouped Lat, grouped Long, max value of group, min value of group, number of points in the cluster}.

I see how to do something similar based on the number of clusters generated, but I can't find how to do this by a distance between points. I feel like I'm missing an obvious thing, since this can be done so easily in the layer symbology.

Comment: Have you tried [DBScan clustering](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#dbscan-clustering)?

Comment: @BERA, this might be exactly what I need. I misunderstood its use before. But now that I have points separated into groups, how could I get the average acceleration of each group?

Comment: You can try [Statistics by categories](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisstatisticsbycategories) with cluster id as category